# Try to post comments, but cannot

Tags: bug, comments, profile-page, ios-app

When I try to post a comment, it says I am not a member and to join, and I click join. Than it says I am already a member and closes. I am bewildered. Any assistance?

If this is the wrong place, I'm terribly sorry. Please move it. 
I'm on iOS, the app.

This only happens in physics/physics meta.

As per request here are screenshots. The second is what pops up when I hit join site. For this error, I tried to up vote an answer.

[image: enter click here]
[image: clock 3]

Comment: You can login via the website on physics?

Comment: It says I'm not logged in. I haven't ever registered on the site. I can post questions/ answers though!

Comment: It also happens when I try to accept an answers/ & vote up/down

Comment: Every anonymous user can post questions and answers...

Comment: But I can comment on any other with this user. Should I register.

Comment: That would be a bug if you can comment everywhere. You need enough rep and an account to vote and to leave comments.

Comment: You are not a member in physics.SE, you need to register there first before commenting.

Comment: So I have this account, I just need more rep? It sdoesnt give me that msg. I'll take screenshots.

Comment: @MeNoTalk I am, I can post questions and answers. When I try to post comments or vote, it says I'm not a member, then when I hit join site it says I'm already a member and only gives me the close option. It's a loop.

Comment: If you have less than 50 reputation, you can't post comments unless it's on your own question or answer.  It's not impossible that there's an issue with the error message.  Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: That's not the issue the issue is the login error.

Comment: Added Per your request

Comment: @user57404 What version of the app are you using?